# HTML push table to next page when printing

Tags: html, css

I have this full html page that is used as a printing template. On this page there is a table with borders. I already added in bage_break_inside: avoid to avoid getting half cutten cells when it can actually fit on next page. Now problem is that when the table start at the near the end, th will be on 1 page, then the table gets stretched and next cell is on the next page. But since it at so bottom it would be better to push it entirely on the next page. How do i do it?

Edit:
A special case emerged. When all table rows are pushed to the next page then at some cases the border of the table remains on the previous page. How can i make it so that when all rows are on the next page, then the border also goes fully on the next page.

Comment: Did you try putting `page-break-inside` on the table itself?

Comment: I added it. IT works asolng as the entire table can fit into a single page. If it can it just ignores it and creates the weird behaviour. page-break-inside the rows solvedit. Now the issue is table border.

Comment: in any case did you find any solution this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS @media print to set styles specifically for printing. You are still limited by the size of the page, but you can use this to save space here and there you can fit it all in 1 page or at least until you feel it looks good enough

```
@media print{
    /* example css rule */
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can styleize it, thats not the problem, problem is how can i set this so called optional page break. Like if the table is like 5%  at the bottom on the page, then it would be better to put it on the next page.